# How to fix error between JSON, jQuery, AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm having problems figuring out what is wrong with my json. I used php's json_encode.So, on every page I have the some form which need be sent on each page to different email address. However, if I comment jQuery file, then the form is submitted correctly, all data inserted into database correctly, and in place of jQuery AJAX response I get valid JSON, like

```
{"response":"success","content":{"3":"Thanks John Doe! Your message is successfully sent to owner of property Hotel Milano!"}}
```

If I want to read and process this data with jQuery instead of get valid response I get just empty [] I was try a lot of options and so if I add JSON_FORCE_OBJECT instead of get empty [] I get empty {}. However if I write json data which need to encode after closing tag for `if (is_array($emails) && count($emails) > 0) {` just then json data it's encoded correctly and when a form is submitted I get valid response, but in this case form isn't sent and data isn't inserted into db. Bellow is my PHP code:

```
<?php
 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// define variables and set to empty values
$fname = $tel = $email_address_id = "";
$error = false;
$response = [];
 
//Load the config file
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "secret";
$dbPassword = "secret";
$dbName = "booking";
$dbCharset = "utf8";

try {
    $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $dbHost . ";dbName=" . $dbName . ";charset=" . $dbCharset;
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbUser, $dbPassword);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $response['response'] = 'error';
    $response['errors'][] = $e->getMessage();
    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
 
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        //print_r($_POST);
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $tel = $_POST['tel'];
 
        if (empty($fname)) {
            $response['response'] = 'error';
            $error = true;
            $response['errors'][] = 'Name can not be empty!';
        } else {
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zšđčćžA-ZŠĐČĆŽ\s]*$/", $fname)) {
                $response['response'] = 'error';
                $error = true;
                $response['errors'][] = 'Name can contain just letters and white space!';
            }
        }

        if (empty($tel)) {
            $response['response'] = 'error';
            $error = true;
            $response['errors'][] = "Phone can not be empty!";
        } else {
            if (!preg_match('/^[\+]?[0-9]{9,15}$/', $tel)) {
                $response['response'] = 'error';
                $error = true;
                $response['errors'][] = "Phone can contain from 9 to 15 numbers!";
            }
        }
 
        if (!$error) {
            // Instantiate a NEW email
            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
            $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Host = 'secret.com';
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
            $mail->Username = 'booking@secret.com';
            $mail->Password = 'secret';
            $mail->Port = 465; // 587
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // tls
            $mail->WordWrap = 50;
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->setFrom('booking@secret.com');
            $mail->clearAddresses();
            $mail->Subject = "New message from secret.com";
 
            $query = "SELECT owners_email.email_address_id, email_address, owner_name, owner_property, owner_sex, owner_type FROM booking.owners_email INNER JOIN booking.pages ON (pages.email_address_id = owners_email.email_address_id) WHERE `owner_sex`='M' AND `owner_type`='other' AND `pages_id` = ?";
            $dbstmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $dbstmt->bindParam(1, $pages_id);
            $dbstmt->execute();
            //var_dump($dbstmt);
            $emails = $dbstmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 
            if (is_array($emails) && count($emails) > 0) {
 
                foreach ($emails as $email) {
                    //var_dump($email['email_address']);
                    $mail->addAddress($email['email_address']);
                    $body = "<p>Dear {$email['owner_name']}, <br>" . "You just received a message from <a href='https://www.secret-booking.com'>secret-booking.com</a><br>The details of your message are below:</p><p><strong>From: </strong>" . ucwords($fname) . "<br><strong>Phone: </strong>" . $tel . "</p>";
                    $mail->Body = $body;
                    if ($mail->send()) {
                        $mail = "INSERT INTO booking.contact_owner (fname, tel, email_address_id) VALUES (:fname, :tel, :email_address_id)";
                        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($mail);
                        $stmt->execute(['fname' => $fname, 'tel' => $tel, 'email_address_id' => $email['email_address_id']]);
 
                        $response['response'] = "success";
                        $response['content'][$email['email_address_id']] = "Thanks " . ucwords($fname) . "! Your message is successfully sent to owner of property {$email['owner_property']}!";
      
                    }//end if mail send
                    else {
                        $response['response'] = "error";
                        $response['content'][$email['email_address_id']] = "Something went wrong! Try again..." . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                    }
                }//end foreach for email addresses
            } //end if for array of emails
/* If use this else for response I allways get this response. Even, if I write JSON for success hier I get it but data isn't sent and isn't inserted into db
else {
                $response['response'] = 'error';
                $response['error'][] = '$emails is either not an array or is empty'; // jQuery just read this
            }//end if else for array of emails
*/
        }//end if validation
    }//end submit
    echo json_encode($response);
}//end REQUEST METHOD = POST
```

And this is jQuery for submitHanfdler

```
 submitHandler: function (form) {
      //Your code for AJAX starts    
      var formData = jQuery("#contactOwner").serialize();
      console.log(formData); //this work
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/classes/Form_process.class.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
         
          jQuery("#response").text(response['content']);
         // debbuger;
          console.log(response);
          //console.log(response.hasOwnProperty('content'));
        }, 
        error: function (response) {
    
         // alert("error");
         jQuery("#responseOwner").text("An error occurred");
          console.dir("Response: " + response);
        }
      }); //Code for AJAX Ends
      // Clear all data after submit
      var resetForm = document.getElementById('contactOwner').reset();
      return false;
    } //submitHandler
```

Thanks in advance for any kind of your help, any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is the dataType: 'json' attribute. This is because the serialize function does not provide json data. See if this works:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/classes/Form_process.class.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: jQuery("#contactOwner").serialize()
}).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to use dataType: 'json', you will need to send in json data:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/classes/Form_process.class.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      firstName: jQuery("#contactOwner .first-name").val(),
      lastName: jQuery("#contactOwner .last-name").val(),
      ...
    }
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
}).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

If you add you data using an object as shown above this should work with dataType: 'json'.

Comment: I was try all two methods, but in all two methods, it's skipped jQuery validation and so need check why this happends and what is errors., However, jQuery use type:POST instead od method, and I was change it, but have some other reason why this file it's skipped, so something is wong.  Allready see, you close AJAXY before done, I have there return false, so there is some problem....I will check now deeply